# How can we pass the functions inside of single sx properties , say ( color, zIndex, backgroundColor) , etc? Is this possible somehow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am making a single search component for all the different places into my application.
And to each component I am passing a prop named `search : string` to check for the truthfulness of that particular component, so as to specify styles for the same.
I know I could use classNames instead of sx prop,  but if I pass the sx prop which contain where every single property received the function , which in turn behaves accordingly to the type of which component is active for that moment. ( or way could say , which component has active), this is because my search bar for homepage has different styling then the search bar for items page.

Here's is my code

```
import { SearchSharp } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { alpha, FormControl, IconButton, InputAdornment, InputBase, makeStyles, styled, SxProps, TextField, Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useThemeContext } from "../../css/ThemeSettings";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../Redux/reduxStore";
import { setSearchTerm } from "./jobSlice";

interface Props {
  search? : string;
}

export default function SearchAll ( props : Props ) {
// using redux
const { searchTerm } = useAppSelector ( state => state.jobs);
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
// using theme
const { darkMode } = useThemeContext();

// background color // this is my function to trigger different backgroundColor based on which component is active...
const setBackgroundColor = () => {
  switch ( props.search ) {
    case 'home' : return darkMode ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)' : 'rgba(238, 240, 243, 1)';
    case 'items' : return 'rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 )';
  }};
```

// similar to the above, i want to make other functions that I could pass into color, // width, position property etc.

```
// making and using styles
const searchStyles = {
  position : 'relative',
  borderRadius : 20,
  color : 'text.secondary',
  width :  props.search === 'home' ? '500px' : '100%',
  backgroundColor : setBackgroundColor(),
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "& > fieldset": { border : "none" } },
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor : props.search === 'items' ? 'none'
                    : darkMode ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)' : 'rgba(238, 240, 243, 1)',
  },
};


  return (
        <Fragment>
                <TextField
                 variant = {'outlined'}
                 size = {'small'}
                 sx = {searchStyles} // i am getting an error here
                
                 placeholder = {"Search…"}
                 fullWidth = { props.search === 'items' ? true : false }
                 autoFocus = { true } />
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

below is the error which I am getting when hovering on 'sx' keyword, as it is the thing which is throwing the error ...

```
The system prop that allows defining system overrides as well as additional CSS styles.

Type '{ position: string; borderRadius: number; color: string; width: string; backgroundColor: string | undefined; "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": { "& > fieldset": { border: string; }; }; '&:hover': { backgroundColor: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.
  Type '{ position: string; borderRadius: number; color: string; width: string; backgroundColor: string | undefined; "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": { "& > fieldset": { border: string; }; }; '&:hover': { backgroundColor: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSSelectorObjectOrCssVariables<Theme>'.
    Property 'backgroundColor' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme> | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number | SystemStyleObject<Theme>)'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject<Theme> | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number |
```

**Is there any way, we could use to pass functions  ( which in turn return string) to these individual sx props?
or is there any another way to achieve this?**

Comment: If it's a utility function you are creating that's accessible across applications, You can create a module and import it into the required component, or create a static function and access it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `setBackgroundColor` you use for setting `backgroundColor` in your `searchStyles` not compatible with the property `backgroundColor` *(Property 'backgroundColor' is incompatible with index signature.)* as is could possible return `undefined` while `backgroundColor` requires a "*SystemStyleObject | CssVariableType | ((theme: Theme) => string | number | SystemStyleObject)*" and does not accept `undefined` as a valid type

You should be able to fix this by adding a `default` case to your `setBackGroundColor` method

```js
const setBackgroundColor = () => {
  switch ( props.search ) {
    case 'home': return darkMode ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)' : 'rgba(238, 240, 243, 1)';
    case 'items': return 'rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 )';
    default: return 'none'
  }};
```

Comment: Thank you Xiduzo for suggesting me, I just skipped adding default here, you are correct. Thanks man : )